# Calculating XIRR in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, excel-formula, xirr

I have been trying to find a solution to calculate XIRR in SQL (TSQL). Ideally, the values would match the values that Excel calculates using the same input data. I have found several suggested solutions around the web but all seem to be flawed in some manner. Below is an example that we have been using that works in *almost* all cases.

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[CalcXIRR]
(
    @Sample XIRRTable READONLY,
    @Rate DECIMAL(19, 9) = 0.1
)
RETURNS DECIMAL(38, 9)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @X DECIMAL(19, 9) = 0.0,
    @X0 DECIMAL(19, 9) = 0.1,
    @f DECIMAL(19, 9) = 0.0,
    @fbar DECIMAL(19, 9) = 0.0,
    @i TINYINT = 0,
    @found TINYINT = 0

IF @Rate IS NULL
    SET @Rate = 0.1

SET @X0 = @Rate

WHILE @i < 100
    BEGIN
        SELECT  @f = 0.0,
            @fbar = 0.0

        SELECT      @f = @f + value * POWER(1 + @X0, (-theDelta / 365.0E)),
        @fbar = @fbar - theDelta / 365.0E * value * POWER(1 + @X0, (-theDelta / 365.0E - 1))
        FROM    (
                SELECT  Value,
                    DATEDIFF(DAY, MIN(date) OVER (), date) AS theDelta
                FROM    @Sample
            ) AS d

        SET @X = @X0 - @f / @fbar

        If ABS(@X - @X0) < 0.00000001
        BEGIN
           SET @found = 1
           BREAK;
        END

        SET @X0 = @X
        SET @i += 1
   END

 If @found = 1
    RETURN  @X

RETURN NULL
END

GO
```

However, with the data below,

[image]

we are getting an error

`An invalid floating point operation occurred.`

This is happening on the line

`SELECT @f = @f + value * POWER(1 + @X0, (-theDelta / 365.0E))`

It essentially gets down to a specific calculation

`POWER(-0.635634780,-0.0849315)`

Could it be that there is some simple syntax adjustment that could fix this error or is the function itself not going to work? Excel seems to handle this calculation without a problem.

This is just one of many examples I have tried using. I can break down another example, if needed. I can edit the post to make it fit Stack Overflow's standard with guidance. I find it very unusual that there is no clear discussion on how to calculate XIRR in SQL. Every solution seems to have problems yet Excel spits out values so effortlessly.

Comment: Raising a negative number to a fractional power is not a real-number operation.  What do you want to happen?  Excel also returns an error, unless you consider `#NUM` to be "without a problem".

Comment: I was suggesting there may be a way to still raise a negative to a fraction in a different way, essentially "tricking" SQL's processor. I know it's far-fetched. In regard to your Excel throwing an error, how are you inputting the data? I am getting a value of -0.6719218.

Comment: . . Well, if you want to invent an imaginary number data type for SQL Server, then it is easily done.  Mathematically, the result is well defined.  It is just not a real number.

Comment: You said you received `#NUM` in Excel when entering the specified data. I'm getting a different output. If Excel was spitting out `#NUM`, that would be consistent with my SQL outputs, which would essentially solve my issue. However, Excel is giving me a value and the SQL function is not. I am simply trying to get each scenario in SQL to match Excel.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your image is in A1 at the top left. Does not solve your SQL but I hope may be of some help:

Firstly, my Excel also returns `-0.6719218`.

Secondly, Excel's calculation is detailed at [XIRR function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/xirr-function-de1242ec-6477-445b-b11b-a303ad9adc9d) from which part is:

[image: XIRR formula]

However, that is for a *series* of cash flows, for which Excel uses iteration, and your specific example is merely a pair of paired entries, for which the soluble equation may be expressed as:

```
=10^(LOG(-A2/A1)*365/(B2-B1))
```

This part: `365/(B2-B1)` is the reciprocal of your `0.0849315`, so it may be worth investigating your `0.635634780` more closely (I'm not clear how you arrived at that).